# How can to convert a flat file into JSON object using Java?

Tags: java, json, csv, parsing

I have a flat file like below:

```
   customerInfo.firstName
   customerInfo.lastName
   customerInfo.nickNames.0.name
   customerInfo.nickNames.0.meaning
```

for the above entries want to construct a JSON object as below:

```
    {
      "customerInfo": {
      "firstName": null,
      "lastName": null,
      "nickNames": [
      {
        "name": null,
        "meaning": null
      }]
     }
    }
```

Note: These lines (entries) can be anything, I can't predefine a class for this.

Comment: Have you though about it ? The only difficulty I see would be the arrays

Comment: what have u tried?

Comment: My search was targeted towards already existing, proven solution. Not sure whats up with the downvote.

Comment: I am getting unexpected characterc [c] at position 0 while parsing the file.How to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using external libraries, you can give this a try.

```
   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser()
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("your_text_file_location"));
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONObject jsonObject=(JSONObject )obj;
    String flattenedJson = JsonFlattener.flatten(jsonObject.toString());
```

Also make sure you add below dependency to pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.wnameless</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-flattener</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where is this parser coming from in this line **Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("your_text_file_location"));**

Comment: I am getting unexpected characterc [c] at position 0 while parsing the file